# How to write exception in build of AsyncNotifier from riverpod

Tags: flutter, exception, riverpod

When not connected to the internet, executing the following code will cause a _ClientSocketException.
How should I write the exception handling?

```dart
class AsyncTodosNotifier extends AsyncNotifier<List<Todo>> {
  Future<List<Todo>> _fetchTodo() async {
    final json = await http.get('api/todos');  //** _ClientSocketException Error occurred**
    final todos = jsonDecode(json) as List<Map<String, dynamic>>;
    return todos.map((todo) => Todo.fromJson(todo)).toList();
  }

  @override
  Future<List<Todo>> build() async {
    return _fetchTodo();
  }
```

Using the AsyncNotifier's build() from riverpod, I would like to code exception handling with AsyncValue.guard, but it results in a syntax error.
How should I write it to make it work?

When trying to get json data, if I can't connect to the internet, I want to write exception handling so that it doesn't abort.

Reference:
https://docs-v2.riverpod.dev/docs/providers/notifier_provider

full code:

```dart
implementation.
@immutable
class Todo {
  const Todo({
    required this.id,
    required this.description,
    required this.completed,
  });

  factory Todo.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> map) {
    return Todo(
      id: map['id'] as String,
      description: map['description'] as String,
      completed: map['completed'] as bool,
    );
  }

  final String id;
  final String description;
  final bool completed;

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => <String, dynamic>{
        'id': id,
        'description': description,
        'completed': completed,
      };
}


class AsyncTodosNotifier extends AsyncNotifier<List<Todo>> {
  Future<List<Todo>> _fetchTodo() async {
    final json = await http.get('api/todos');　//** _ClientSocketException Error occurred**
    final todos = jsonDecode(json) as List<Map<String, dynamic>>;
    return todos.map((todo) => Todo.fromJson(todo)).toList();
  }

  @override
  Future<List<Todo>> build() async {
    return _fetchTodo();
  }

  Future<void> addTodo(Todo todo) async {
    state = const AsyncValue.loading();
    state = await AsyncValue.guard(() async {
      await http.post('api/todos', todo.toJson());
      return _fetchTodo();
    });
  }
}

final asyncTodosProvider =
    AsyncNotifierProvider<AsyncTodosNotifier, List<Todo>>(() {
  return AsyncTodosNotifier();
});
```

Comment: Any error that is thrown in build() is captured directly into an AsyncError value, as if you had used AsyncValue.guard.  Doesn't that suffice?

Comment: I had the same thought, but it resulted in a ClientSocketException.
When using **addTodo()**, a comment will be displayed on the screen with an AsyncError value, but the first time it is loaded(when **build()**execute), it will result in a ClientSocketException.